# Calling class member (IService) by method in another thread

Tags: c#

I want to implement a template method in my class, therefore I have an abstract base class with protected members.
In the concrete class I want to use this members in a method which is called by another thread.

Now my question is - is that safe?

```
public abstract class ClassBase
{
    protected IService service = new Service();

    protected internal abstract Method();
}


public sealed class Class : ClassBase
{
    public void RunAsync()
    {
       InvokeAsync(Method); //Just a sample - runs asyncrounus
    }

    protected internal override Method()
    {
       var v = this.service.GetById(125);
       ...
    }
}
```

Or do I have to create Service type within the Method() in the inherited class?
It's just a service class which handles database operations.

Comment: "Safe" in what way?  Is this WPF, Silverlight, etc?

Comment: SAFE in general - that class can be used in all Frameworks.
I have implemented the EAP pattern with sync to the caller thread so it works on the GUI.

So the main question is if I can handle members in base class in the Method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each application has their own definition of "safe", especially in terms of thread safety. (e.g. `Console` is thread safe but you can change `Console.OutputEncoding` on one thread and affect how another thread outputs text--which may not be "safe" for a particular application).  Your code is "safe" in so much as `service` can't be corrupted by any other thread--it will always have a "valid" value (all `object` assignments are atomic in .NET), but it could change between when `InvokeAsync` is called and when `Method` is invoked--which may not be "safe" for the application.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late answer - wasn't in the office.
So when I make the IService member in the base class "readonly" is it safe for my purpose?
The IService type itself has also a member (object) which is marked as readonly.

Comment: Many times of assginments are "atomic" in .net (including reference assignments).  This isn't enough to make something thread-safe--hence the need for things like `Mutex`, `lock`, `InterlockedExchange`.  Based strictly on the code you've posted, your use of `service` is thread-safe--but that doesn't mean any other code is thread safe.